# How can I replace inline styles in css

Tags: css

I have a page in which many elements of the same class are to the left, some in the center and some to the right, I also have many elements that sometimes are display:inline and sometimes display:block.

I ran a CSS validator that told me to put it into the stylesheet, but I don't feel like creating class1 left, class1 center, class1 right, class1 inline,...
Can I have something in my stylesheet so that I can do this

```
<div class="class1 left inline"></div>
```

Instead of this

```
<div class="class1" align="left" display="inline"></div>
```

Keep in mind that I have almost zero experience in CSS

Comment: C'mon, have you tried doing any research on how this would work? Every single CSS tutorial out there covers this immediately after teaching inline styles.

Comment: Yes, you technically can, if you're just starting out. Keep in mind that it's very bad practice to have presentational class names, but you can treat it as an intermediate step to fully abstracting your layout into CSS. I still suggest reading up a tutorial or something - Stack Overflow expects askers to do at least a modicum of research if they're new to something.

Comment: I don't know what to search for. Can you link a tutorial?

Comment: Worth a read http://blog.terriblelabs.com/blog/2012/01/04/step-away-from-the-presentational-classes/

Comment: But my problem is that I have elements like h1 that appear at the center, at the left, red, blue, yellow,...

Comment: Why can't I create some classes that will make it centered or inline, rather than creating a whole new class just for that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your html structure like this u want to use.

```
<div class="class1 left inline"></div>
```

And in Css file create classes for the same like following:

```
left{
 float:left;
}
right{
 float:right;
}
inline{
 display:inline;
}

class1{
 /*all your style elements*/
}
```

Read these for more information:

https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Thank you. I discovered that it wasn't working because I was using text-align. :facepalm: